# Unable to upload file using Bootstrap 5/Fastapi

Tags: fastapi, bootstrap-5

I am trying to upload a file using bootstrap 5 and fastapi.

Here is my html upload file block

```
 <div class="mt-lg-3 mb-3">
      <label for="formFile" class="form-label">Upload template (formats: .j2 or .html only)</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" accept=".j2,.html" id="formFile" name="formFile">
    </div>
```

when I submit the form its sending the file as string
Error: **{"detail":[{"loc":["body","formFile"],"msg":"Expected UploadFile, received: <class 'str'>","type":"value_error"}]}**

if I use the api its working fine. Can someone help me?

Comment: At least give your FastAPI code base?

Comment: You'll also have to include your `form` element, since that has to have `multipart/form-data` as its `enctype` attribute to support regular file uploads.

Comment: @MatsLindh Added enctype="multipart/form-data" to form element and it worked. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Added enctype="multipart/form-data" to form element and it worked. thank you @Mat for the solution